# Kuberentes Ingress rate lmiting altering rewrite-target base

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, kubernetes-ingress, api-gateway

I have an Ingress file which contains **only one annotation**:

```
---
  apiVersion: "extensions/v1beta1"
  kind: "Ingress"
  metadata: 
    name: "logging-microservice-ingress"
    namespace: "000000001"
    annotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  spec: 
    rules: 
      - 
        host: "ms-shared-nad.techmahindra.com"
        http: 
          paths: 
            - 
              backend: 
                serviceName: "logging-microservice-000000001"
                servicePort: 3000
              path: "/logging-microservice"
```

When I call `https://example.com/logging-microservice/logs` **backend** service generates,

`GET /logs --> 200`

When I added **two more annotations** like

```
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-connections: 1
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: 1
```

**backend** gives

`GET /logging-microservice/logs --> 404`

I don't have access to see the actual nginx configuration being generated there. But, wondering how applying rate limiting can alter the rewrite base.

I have tried rate limiting in `open source nginx server` and it works as expected. What could be the change to remove path from the url which is passed to the upstream api backend?

---

### Update :

I have accessed the cluster and record the changes happening:

```
location ~* "^/logging-microservice" {
    rewrite "(?i)/logging-microservice" / break;
}
location ~* "^/" {
}
```

is changing to

```
location /logging-microservice {

}
location / {
}
```

when rate limiting annotations are added.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you were given with Ingress.yaml with

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /`

and everything was working fine, you need it like

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"`

Other thing is, order of annotations matters;

it can't be :

```
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-connections: "1"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: "1"
```

it should be :

```
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-connections: "1"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: "1"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"
```

learned the hard way!